# Jaysvcutil generates no classes 2

Tags: edmx, jaydata

Hi I'm trying to learn JayData but ran quickly into a problem.

I have exactly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495200/jaysvcutil-generates-no-classes) problem. My Metadata looks like this:

```
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0" 
    xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx">
    <edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="1.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0" 
        xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
        <Schema Namespace="NAV" 
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/05/edm">
            <EntityType Name="contact">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="No" />
                </Key>
                <Property Name="No" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="Type" Type="Edm.String" />
```

So I think the `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/05/edm">` is the important line.
And if I look at [Github](https://github.com/jaydata/JaySvcUtil/blob/master/Program.cs) i can see the `{"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/05/edm", "V1.1" }` so I think it should work. Or am I doing somethign wrong?

I tried it with:

`--metadataUri http://localh.. --out nav.js --namespace NAV --v V11`,

`--metadataUri http://localh.. --out nav.js --namespace NAV --v V1.1`
and all other possibilities, but could not get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works when using this...

```
    // Source
    var myContext = new NAV.NAV({ 
        name: "oData", 
        oDataServiceHost: "http://localhost:7048/DynamicsNAV71/OData/Company('CRONUS%20(Schweiz)%20AG')" 
    });
```

but I can't accept my own answer..